# Read line n of a textfile in java then output result into an int

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will read line n of a provided text file, using a `BufferedReader`, and convert this line's contents into an `int`. This is the code I am currently using, but it fails to output an `int`:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
int LineContent;

try {
   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\SAVEdata\\Save.txt");
   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       LineContent = Integer.parseInt(line);
        if (LineContent == 0) {
            CHRSelectWorld w = new CHRSelectWorld();
            Greenfoot.setWorld(w);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read and parse every line in your file. If you want nth line, you can use `Files` class

`String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).get(n);`

It will work well for files of small-medium size.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in asking. Which lines in my program should I replace with this line?

Comment: All lines. ;) - leave only the try-catch

Comment: That doesn't output to the int LineContent, which is essential for this program.

Answer (score 1):

```
long n = 42L;
Path path = Paths.get(
        "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\SAVEdata\\Save.txt");
Optional<String> line =
        Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())
    .skip(n - 1)
    .findFirst();

if (line.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Insufficient lines, less than " + n);
}
System.out.println(line.orElse("(No line found)");
```

The class Files has many goodies, and with streams it is almost a one-liner.

Comment: What do I replace in my original program with this?

Comment: The code starts with `n`, the line number and the file path. The optional result is the line.